# How to make sure php files cannot be edited in a shared hosting evironment

Tags: php, mysql, security, hosting, slim

Please how do I make sure an intruder can not edit files on my shared hosting account

I have changed the hosting account password

The ftp password

disabled ssh

disabled dangerous php functions file_put_contents, system, exec, etc

Changed file permissions to 444 and directory permissions to 555

but the intruder is still able to edit files

Please is there any way I can stop this, or is there anything I am missing

Comment: Sounds like there maybe a compromise in the code you are running. Is it your code or a a Framework or a site like WordPress.

Comment: My code mainly using Slim Framework and Illuminiate database